# Installing NodeJS on RHEL(4)?

Tags: node.js, deployment, installation, web-deployment, rhel

To the kind people of SO,

I am having trouble finding any resources for installing NodeJS (current or earlier version) onto a RHEL4 box.  I am starting to doubt if this is even possible as the OS dates back 10 years now.  The machine has Python 2.3.4 and GCC 3.4.6, if that's of any help.

I am hoping someone here could maybe point me in the right direction, I feel I may be grasping for straws at this point.

Comment: With such a outdated box, you will probably have to compile from source, I doubt a package exist. Did you considered upgrading the OS instead?

Comment: Also, did you tried [the official way](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora)?

Comment: Yeah I figured I'd have to compile from source, it should be an interesting venture.  I have not yet tried the official way, gotta wait for su on the box so I can get yum on there.  Everything needs to get updated on it as far as the python and GCC versions, and then hopefully, maybe it'll install.

Comment: As far as updating the OS, unfortunately that is not a possibility.

Comment: And if you can't have yum/sudo right, compiling will be hard since you ll have to track dependencies, but you don't need sudo nor yum. Another last option would be to track down the last node.js version officially supported for RHEL 4, and try with that one.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for, the last version of node with RHEL 4, I was scrolling through the legacy downloads for a while but I had no luck finding it.  And with the little relevant results that come up with some google searches I am starting to think that it may have never been officially supported.

Comment: Interesting, I don't need sudo or yum?  I am really new when it comes to Linux and building from source, I will look into trying to compile from source.  That's for the input @DrakaSAN I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a handful of possibility, since from comment, you said upgrading the box is not a option. (I d like you to know there is security implications too, you should have a up-to-date OS):

- Install the [official way](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora), which need yum and sudo rights.
- Compile from source, which in theory doesn't need sudo rights nor yum.

Note that, even if compiling from source should be easy:

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/node-v4.4.7-linux-x86.tar.gz
tar -xzf node-v4.4.7-linux-x86.tar.gz
cd ./node-v4.4.7-linux-x86
./configure #Options
make
make install
```

You will almost always run into issues because of not installed or outdated dependencies. At this step, you may want to track down a previously supported version of node.js for RHEL4 (0.10.x?), or try to make a case about upgrading the box.

Comment: Thank you for going out of your way my friend.  I actually "solved" the issue by convincing them to upgrade the OS.